# Discord.js InteractionAlreadyReplied – sending select menu and after it modal

Tags: discord.js, interaction

I have this code for my discord bot. When it receives slash command, it replies with select menu, where you pick from .json file, all working. Then, when you select option, it should send a modal with text input so you can change params in the .json, butit doesnt send, with error "InteractionAlreadyReplied The reply to this interaction has already been sent or deferred"

```
    } else if (testOption === 'upravit') {
            const database = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('events/testy.json', 'utf8'));

            const currentDate = new Date();
            const currentDateString = currentDate.toISOString().slice(0, 10).replace(/-/g, ''); // Format to YYYYMMDD

            const options = database.entries
                .filter(entry => {
                    return entry.datum >= currentDateString;
                })
                .map(entry => {
                    const entryDate = new Date(
                        entry.datum.substring(0, 4),
                        entry.datum.substring(4, 6) - 1, // Month is zero-based
                        entry.datum.substring(6, 8)
                    );

                    const formattedDate = entryDate.toLocaleDateString('cs-CZ', {
                        day: '2-digit',
                        month: '2-digit',
                        year: 'numeric'
                    });

                    return {
                        label: entry.predmet,
                        description: `${entry.tema}, naplánováno na ${formattedDate}`,
                        value: entry.id.toString()
                    };
                });

            const select = new StringSelectMenuBuilder()
                .setCustomId('pick-test')
                .setPlaceholder('Testy')
                .addOptions(options);

            const row = new ActionRowBuilder()
                .addComponents(select);

            try {
                await interaction.reply({
                    content: 'Vyber test pro upravení.',
                    components: [row],
                });
        
                const userInteraction = await interaction.channel.awaitMessageComponent({
                    filter: i => i.customId === 'pick-test' && i.user.id === interaction.user.id,
                    time: 60000
                });
        
                if (!userInteraction) {
                    await interaction.followUp({ content: 'Vypršel čas na výběr.' });
                    return;
                }
        
                const selectedTestId = userInteraction.values[0];

                const modal = new ModalBuilder()
                    .setCustomId('test-edit')
                    .setTitle('Upravení testu');

                const idTestu = selectedTestId
                
                const newTema = new TextInputBuilder()
                    .setLabel('Nové téma testu')
                    .setCustomId('newTema-testu')
                    .setRequired(false)
                    .setPlaceholder(`(nepovinné)`)
                    .setStyle(TextInputStyle.Short);
                
                const newDate = new TextInputBuilder()
                    .setCustomId('newDate-testu')
                    .setLabel('Nové datum testu')
                    .setStyle(TextInputStyle.Short)
                    .setPlaceholder(`ve formátu YYYYMMDD (nepovinné)`)
                    .setRequired(false)
                    .setMaxLength(8);
                
                const firstActionRow = new ActionRowBuilder().addComponents(idTestu);
                const secondActionRow = new ActionRowBuilder().addComponents(newTema);
                const thirdActionRow = new ActionRowBuilder().addComponents(newDate);
                
                modal.addComponents(firstActionRow, secondActionRow, thirdActionRow);
                
                await interaction.showModal(modal);
            } catch (error) {
                console.error(error);
                await interaction.followUp({ content: 'Nastala chyba při zpracování příkazu.', ephemeral: true });
            }

        }
```

Tried to change this

`await userInteraction.reply({ content: ' ', components: [modal] });`

also used

`interaction.followUp` and `interaction.deferReply`

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1):

You are sending a Modal for an `interaction`. This should be sent to `userInteraction`.

```
- await interaction.showModal(modal);
+ await userInteraction.showModal(modal);
```